# Best way to locate id by email address

Tags: asp.net, function, methods

I have a custom user table that stores the userId along with their email address. I am wrote a function that accepts two parameters, the id and the email. If the email  exists, in the table, I would like to retrieve the id. At this point, I can not locate the id. Below is the code so far. Any help from the community is appreciated.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> UserEmailId(int id, string email)
{

   return UserEmailId(id, email);
}
```

Comment: Change the whole method to `return _context.Person.Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Id == id);` I'd also suggest having two separate functions - one that searches by `id` and one by `email`, rather than just the single function.

Comment: Are you trying to find _all users_ with a matching e-mail address or id, or are you trying to find a single user? Why are you recursively calling the method?

Comment: Hi John, so the idea is that I am trying to locate a single user with their unique email address. Once I find their email address, I want to locate the id.

Comment: @Chris does my edit answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so given what you state you want to do in the comments:

```
public int UserIdFromEmail(string email)
{
   var person = _context.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);
   if (person != null)
   {
     return person.Id;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Note that I assume id field is int, and I return -1 if no user found. This may not be the best thing to do in the actual context (why not just return the Person object), but given your stated requirements, it does the job you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go ahead and assume you have got things very confused, and that you either want to find all users where the email/id match, or you want to find a single user where the email/id matches.

Return all people where the email OR id match:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> UserEmailId(int id, string email)
{
    return _context.Person.Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Id == id);
}
```

Return first person whose email OR id matches:

```
public Person UserEmailId(int id, string email)
{
    return _context.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email || x.Id == id);
}
```

Return first person whose email, (or if none is found), id matches:

```
public Person UserEmailId(int id, string email)
{
    return _context.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email) ?? _context.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

If none of these are your use case, please edit your question to clarify what you want to do and I'll take another look.

Edit in response to your comment:

> Hi John, so the idea is that I am trying to locate a single user with their unique email address. Once I find their email address, I want to locate the id.

`.Where(...)` is a filter. You still get an enumerable from this, even if you have a single item in that enumerable.

If you want to find a user by email address and get their id, you need to do something like this:

```
public int? GetUserIdByEmail(string email)
{
    return _context.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email)?.Id;
}
```

Breaking it down:

- `FirstOrDefault` will filter by email and return the first person entity it finds (or null, if it isn't found).
- `?.` will short-circuit the evaluation if `null` is returned by `FirstOrDefault`, and it will reutrn `(int?)null` if it short circuits.
- `?.Id` takes the Person entity's `Id` property value and returns it.

Basically, you just want to find your `Person` entity, and then you can access it to get other information.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thank you for the explanation.